# enter facebook based login details in mysql db

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am looking to create facebook login system in my website using javascript SDK. I am able to login as per details mentioned in facebook website. I am trying to enter data in mysql database primarily email ID of users. I am unable to do so despite different options. Need help. also how to disappear login button once user is logged into the system. Please help. below is the basic code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId      : 'XXXX', 
     channelUrl : '//XXXX', 
     status     : true, 
     cookie     : true, 
     xfbml      : true  
    });

 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
   if (response.status === 'connected') {
     testAPI();
   } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
     FB.login();
   } else {
     FB.login();
   }
  });
  };
  (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
 $.post('send.php', {'name':response.name}); 
 alert('Good to see you, ' + response.email + '.');
 });
 }
 </script>


<fb:login-button show-faces="true" autologoutlink="true" scope="user_about_me,email" width="200" size= "large" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you are trying to save the details in the database

Comment: thats what i am trying to find a method for

Comment: $.post('send.php', { option:'fb_register', name:response.name, email:response.email}, function (data) {
        alert('registerd')

Comment: put in details of the code...pls pls help

Comment: What's the problem with the code above?

Comment: email is not showing up and secondly data is not passing through send.php

Comment: While auth, did fb asked for the permissions you added?

Comment: yes added permissions and email is started to show up

Comment: now the only problem is that i cant pass data to another file

Comment: Can you please dit the ques, and add the code that you have used